# Input Python Output's into a different program

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface

At this moment I have a Python GUI program that outputs some data, I want to find a way to take the outputs and input them into a different running program. I've been searching for a way to do this for a while and can't seem to find a way.

Thanks all help appreciated!!!

Edit:

Program one with GUI (Designed by me) outputs strings.
Program two running in commandline (not designed by me and do not have access to source code).

I need program one outputs to go into the commandline of program two. The way I am thinking about it is that I am trying to interface between them.

Comment: What is the output stream (like stdout or any file)? You can easily write all outputs to a file and that file can be read by the other program assuming that its a simple program settings you need.

Comment: Its not that simple, thats the problem. I'm dealing with stdout but the other program is not designed to deal with reading files such as a simple .txt. I need to take the output from my python code and bassically "type it" into a running program. Not sure I explained this well enough.

Comment: Imagine that a user inputs 'name', that name is then outputed and needs to be written into another running program. The best way I can describe this is basically copied and pasted into the running program.

Comment: Does the 2nd program require it's input as arguments that are subjected when you launch it via the commandline, or does it only accept input once it is already up and running? And is it fully closed source or do you have access to some of it's files?

Comment: If it only accepts input once it is already up and running the only way I could think of achieving what you want is on macOS by writing an osascript to simulate all the steps you'd normally take.. but it will be clumsy

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the data out to an output file for the first program, then Read that output file as an input for the second program.

Comment: Read my comments above. I haven't explained it well enough.

Comment: What kind of values your first program outputs that the second program has to read? and why can't you design the second one to read the input data from a file?

Comment: I think am struggling to explain this. Basically the first program outputs strings. The second program is running in command line, and cannot read files, as it was not designed by me. I am basically creating a interface between these two programs. I take the output for my program 1 and put it into command line of program two.

Comment: Can you try to read the output file of first through CMD? Some help: https://www.windows-commandline.com/read-file-from-command-line/

Comment: Ahh. I think you put me on the right track :) What a need is to save the output as a text file and then pass it to the program 2 using a batch file.